# How to drawtext in ffmpeg with box sampled from video?

Tags: ffmpeg, drawtext

As can be seen in these [video screenshots](https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/22291118/ASL_Bible__1_.jpg), I would like to **replace** the hardcoded text in the upper left of the videos to another language.

What comes to mind is [`drawtext`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) with a box. Due to different gradient backgrounds, I was thinking if there is a way so the drawtext box is (1) a **gradient** ([`geq`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#geq)?) and (2) the colors are **automatically sampled** from the video background (along the edges of the box).

For each specific [video file](https://www.jw.org/finder?wtlocale=ASL&pub=nwt), the background gradient doesn't change, so it can be sampled only once for each file.

Any suggestions on how this might be achieved?

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry this doesn't answer your question but I just thought I'd point out that it's more accessible to use your player's closed captions api if at all possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FFmpeg [delogo filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#delogo)**

For the videos above, I used: (set `show=1` to test)

`delogo=x=85:y=47:w=300:h=40:show=0`

`drawtext` filter can be used with `delogo` in one go in `ffmpeg`/`ffplay` on chained `-vf` values.

`delogo` results are impressive. I wonder what the algos are. Pretty fast too.